# Getting WordPress images into the Media Library after migration

Tags: mysql, wordpress, image, media

I am moving from one WordPress host to another. I'm stuck at getting migrated images to show up in the media library.

This is what I did:

- I zipped and downloaded all the files in the wp-content/uploads folder and then unzipped them into the new server's upload directory.
- I exported the wp_posts data:`select * from wp_posts where post_type='attachment'` and all the wp_postmeta with those post_id's.
- I did a search and replace in the SQL files to update the domain name.
- None of those `wp_posts.ID` or `wp_postmeta.meta_id`'s conflicted with the new database, so I imported the SQL files.

The data is in the tables, but still nothing is showing up in the media library. The date filter drop down list in the Media Library is showing all the months for the folders, but it's not showing any images "No Media Files Found".

The images are in the right place, since the page builder I'm using is showing all the images properly (with the new domain name in their URLs).

Is there an extra step I'm missing to get the images on the new server to show up in the media library?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the export the wp_post data or wp_postmeta.

Here's how I migrate my websites manually:

1. Export the whole database and download the files.
2. Import the whole database and copy the files on the root folder.
3. Then on your phpmyadmin and run these scripts, select `wp_options` table:

   UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://www.oldurl', 
   'http://www.newurl') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

   4. On the `wp_posts` table run these:

   UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://www.oldurl','http://www.newurl');

   UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://www.oldurl', 'http://www.newurl');

   5. On `wp_postmeta` table run this:

   UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,'http://www.oldurl','http://www.newurl');

Make sure to change the urls. This will fix the images and other media that are not showing because the url is broken or your site is showing the old url.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm just trying to export/import only pages and media. I don't want anything else overwritten.

Comment: If that's the case. You can export data from wordpress dashboard. Go to Wp Dashboard->Tools->Export. Select the data you want to export then download. You will get the xml file. Then import the xml file to the new website under Tool->Import.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to migrate to another host and keep the links and images intact is to use the plugin called [All in One WP Migration](https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/)

The Step to follow is:

1. Install the plugin on your website
2. Create a backup, the result will be .wpress, download it
3. In the new host, install a clean copy of WP
4. Install the plugin on this new website
5. Import the .wpress backup

This will tell you that all data of your new installation will be replaced by the one from your previous host but all links will be updated. So `old-domain.com` will be replaced by `new-domain.com` without making changes anywhere (database or content).

Tested this many times so I know it works well. There is a reason why it has 1+M downloads.

Comment: Thanks. But I only want to migrate pages and images and not any other data.